# Non linear operator from $\ell^{25}$ to $\ell^{12}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm having trouble determining if the operator $ F:\ell^{25}\to \ell^{12}$ defined as $$F(x_1,...,x_n,...)=(x_1^{2018},...,x_n^{2018},...)$$ is continuous or not.
Clearly the operator isn't linear so an estimate of type $||F(x)||_{12}\le C||x||_{25}$ is useless.